# Subgroups and Direct Products of $\pi$-closed groups are also $\pi$-closed.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $K$ be a class of finite groups, then this class is called *closed* iff

i) homomorphic images of groups in $\mathcal K$ lie in $\mathcal K$,

ii) subgroups of groups from $\mathcal K$ lie in $\mathcal K$,

iii) direct products of groups form $\mathcal K$ lie in $\mathcal K$.

A finite group is called $\pi$-closed, if $G/O_{\pi}(G)$ is a $\pi'$-group, where $O_{\pi}(G)$ is the largest $\pi$-normal subgroup of $G$. For a set of primes $\pi$ a group is called a $\pi$-group if just primes from $\pi$ divide its order, and a $\pi'$-group if just primes not from $\pi$ divide its order. If we denote by $O^{\pi}(G)$ the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ such that its factor group is a $\pi$-group, then a group $G$ is $\pi$-closed precisely when 
$$
 O_{\pi}(G) = O^{\pi'}(G).
$$
I want to show that the class of all $\pi$-closed groups is a closed class (I guess this to be true).

I have found a proof for homomorphic images, but I am stuck on showing it for subgroups and direct products. If $N \unlhd G$, then
$$
 O_{\pi}(N) = N \cap O_{\pi}(G)
$$
and so in this case a little rearranging with the isomorphism theorems yields that $N$ is $\pi$-closed. But I have no idea how to proceed for arbitrary subgroups of $G$, so any ideas? And also how to show it for direct products?

Comment: If $H \le G$ then clearly $H \cap O_\pi(G) \le O_\pi(H)$, and  $H/(H \cap O_\pi(G)) \cong HO_\pi(G)/O_\pi(G)$ is a $\pi'$-group.  It seems obvious that $O_\pi(G \times H) = O_\pi(G) \times O_\pi(H)$.

Comment: A finite group is $\pi$-closed iff the set of all $\pi$-elements is a subgroup.

Comment: @DerekHolt: For me $O_{\pi}(G)\times O_{\pi}(H) \le O_{\pi}(G\times H)$ is obvious, but $O_{\pi}(G\times H) \le O_{\pi}(H)\times O_{\pi}(G)$ not so?

Comment: @Stefan: What is the relation between $O_\pi(G)$ and $O_\pi(G\times H)\cap G$ (considering $G$ as subgroup of $G\times H$)?

Comment: @j.p. We have $O_{\pi}(G) = O_{\pi}(G\times H) \cap G$, but I do not see that $O_{\pi}(G \times H) \le (O_{\pi}(G\times H)\cap G)\times (O_{\pi}(G\times H)\cap H)$ has to hold, as in general the relation $U \le (U\cap A)\times (U\cap B)$ does not hold, for example take $U = \{ (0,0), (1,1) \}$ and $A=B=C_2$.

Comment: @Stefan: You're right. Sorry. I was going into the wrong direction. I should have asked about the image $X = p_1(O_\pi(G\times H))$ of $O_\pi(G\times H)$ under the projection $p_1 : G\times H\to G, (g, h) \mapsto g$ to the first coordinate. What do you know about $X\le G$?

Comment: @j.p. Let $X := p_1(O_{\pi}(G\times H)), Y := p_2(O_{\pi}(G\times H))$, then as $X,Y$ are normal and $\pi$-groups, we have $X \le O_{\pi}(G), Y \le O_{\pi}(H)$ and therefore $X\times Y \le O_{\pi}(G)\times O_{\pi}(H)$. Also for arbitrary sets $Z \le A\times B$ we have $Z \le p_1(Z)\times p_2(Z)$, and therefore $O_{\pi}(G\times H) \le X\times Y \le O_{\pi}(G)\times O_{\pi}(H)$, so this gives the other direction. Thanks!